# Removing space from embedded gist that contains markdown only

Tags: latex, github-flavored-markdown, gist

I am trying to create a gist that contains one markdown cell only. I would like to create the gist using a .ipynb file, which nicely renders the code with LaTex. However, after the embedded gist is generated there is a huge padding after the text (not on gist but on the website where I place the embedded gist). Does anyone know how I can get rid of the space at the bottom? Here are the pictures.

Here is how it shows on gist itself.
[image: on gist]

And here is how it shows on the website after I paste the embedded gist.
[image: on website]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the parent container. I do not work with .ipynb files. Try controlling the size of the Gist using CSS. Stackoverflow has answers that cover including CSS into your notebooks.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .gist {
     overflow:auto;
     width:400px;
  }

  .gist .blob-wrapper.data {
     max-width:400px;
     max-height:400px;
     overflow:auto;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. But will you be able to add LaTex text this way in the gist?

Comment: The display format of a Gist is created by GitHub (Gist -> HTML). I don't know if GitHub supports LaTex. This link might help you: https://gist.github.com/a-rodin/fef3f543412d6e1ec5b6cf55bf197d7b

Comment: @BehrouzB - I recommend creating a new question on LaTex + Gist.

Comment: Yes it does. It successfully creates LaTex formatted text on gist. However, when embedding the gist in a website, white space is added. My issue is how I can remove the white space.

Comment: @BehrouzB - What whitespace are you referring to? The image in your question is not whitespace. That is caused by the sizing of the element. My answer shows how to set the element sizing. Review the actual HTML that is generated in the browser.